# Rails4 new template .erb creation Not Happening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have generated scaffold and created a view called "appointment"
I wanted to added a template .erb file called inbox_mail.html.erb in appointment folder.

I did setting like this.

```
route.rb
get '/appointments/inbox_mail'
```

In appointment controller

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
  def inbox_mail
  end
end
```

Now running the link 3000/appointments/inbox_mail

but giving rise error as,

```
Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound in AppointmentsController#show
Problem: Document(s) not found for class Appointment with id(s) delete_appointment. Summary: When calling Appointment.find with an id or array of ids, each parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be raised. The search was for the id(s): delete_appointment ... (1 total) and the following ids were not found: delete_appointment. Resolution: Search for an id that is in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned instead of raising this error when searching for a single id, or only the matched documents when searching for multiples.
```

Help me in Rails4...!!!!

May be this is b'z of

```
def set_appointment
@appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: What is the code of your `delete_appointment.html.erb` file?

Comment: just added header <h1>display</h1>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is because of `set_appointment` method. I guess you should add `:id` segment to your route, like

```
match '/appointments/delete_appointment/:id', to: 'appointments#delete_appointment', via: :get
```

and this should work.

Comment: giving ArgumentError, missing :controller

Comment: Giving error as Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound in AppointmentsController#show same above error

Comment: @RubyOnRails are you giving proper ID?

Comment: @RubyOnRails So you don't need to find that specific `Appointment` for this action?

Answer (score 1):

Delete something shouldn't be done through GET, you should use the DELETE method. So, when you create the link with "link_to" you should do:

```
link_to 'Delete appointment', delete_appointment_path(@appointment.id), method: :delete
```

you need a route like:

```
delete '/appointments/delete_appointment/:id', to: 'appointments#delete_appointment'
```

Then rails will take care of that and do a DELETE request with the appointment's id, then on your controller you can use @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])

You may want some kind of validation to render a "not found" template:

```
def delete_appointment
  unless @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to appointment_not_found_path #something_like_that
  end
end
```

EDIT: it looks like some before_filter is messing up there too, you talked about "delete_appointment", the error say the action called is "show" and you copied the code for the action/before_filter "set_appointment", check that first

EDIT 2: you say you are not doing any delete, then use get, the important part is the :id on the url if you need to find an appointment by an ID you need that on the url. If you don't need the ID then check your before filters, I guess you have something like

```
before_filter :set_appointment
```

you may want to skip that filter on delete_appointment

```
before_filter :set_appointment, except: :delete_appointment
```

Comment: i am not doing delete functionality, but i am creating a normal template.

Comment: ok, check my edit, you may want to skip a before_filter, I assume you have that or maybe some filter is redirecting to the show action (that's would explain the error saying it's in the "show" action)

Comment: don't change the question that much (now it's something about inbox_mail and the error still say it's something on delete_appointment), you should be clear or you will be downvoted